# Unit testing .Net Core Library – could not load file or Assembly

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core

I wrote a simple Class Library with a method **GetNodes** to examine content of the chosen directory.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public void GetNodes(string directoryPath)
        {
            if (directoryPath == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("directoryPath");

            //Remove white-space characters from the start and end of path.
            directoryPath = directoryPath.Trim();

            bool isWindows = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);

(...)

}
```

***project.json:***

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.3.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Project has been built successfully.

Then in order to perform some unit tests I created a simple Unit Test project (.Net Framework 4.6)

```
[TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
        public void DetectException_WhenCorrectExceptionIsThrown()
        {
            FileManager fm = new FileManager();

            fm.GetNodes(@"c:\");
        }
```

Every time I run the test I get this error:

```
Test Name:  DetectException_WhenCorrectExceptionIsThrown
Test FullName:  Task_2_Test.FileManagerTests.DetectException_WhenCorrectExceptionIsThrown
Test Source:    D:\Git\task_2\Task_2\test\Task_2_Test\FileManagerTests.cs : line 25
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,0152049

Result StackTrace:  
at Task_2.FileManager.GetNodes(String directoryPath)
   at Task_2_Test.FileManagerTests.DetectException_WhenCorrectExceptionIsThrown() in D:\Git\task_2\Task_2\test\Task_2_Test\FileManagerTests.cs:line 30
Result Message: 
Test method Task_2_Test.FileManagerTests.DetectException_WhenCorrectExceptionIsThrown threw exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException, but exception System.ArgumentNullException was expected. Exception message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Git/task_2/Task_2/test/Task_2_Test/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Task_2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\VISUAL STUDIO EXPRESS 2015\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Git/task_2/Task_2/test/Task_2_Test/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Git/task_2/Task_2/test/Task_2_Test/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Git/task_2/Task_2/test/Task_2_Test/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Git/task_2/Task_2/test/Task_2_Test/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.EXE.
```

I see that this error is connected with System.Runtime.InteropServices (I use this library to check the current OS in order to verify correct syntax of the directory path).

I don’t want to resign from this feature, but I have no idea how to deal with this.

Btw. My Ide is Visual Studio Community 2015.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Try to use VS2017 RC. That's the latest and the only way to use the latest SDK and IDE feature. Forget about project.json.

Comment: Shouldn't your class library have a dependency on `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation`?

Comment: I installed VS2017 RC and this worked out well. I guess my last IDE had some integrity issues (had to repair installation, missing packages etc.)

Comment: I would mark the correct answer, but curiously enough this option isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

you may use xunit for as your unit test framework.
I had issues with adding xunit via vs2015 update 3 too, i published my work around on http://jickingnotes.blogspot.com/2016/10/add-xunit-test-project-in-net-core.html

Answer (score 0):

in my case I spotted the reason was update to 2017, and a lot not needed properties in PropertyGroup of csproj. Like RuntimeFrameworkVersion, NetStandardImplitPackageVersion